# NServiceBus routing to SOAP endpoint

Tags: nservicebus

We are investigating using NServiceBus for our ESB implementation.  We have several external partners that do not use Microsoft technologies.  Is there a way of routing using NServiceBus to a SOAP or REST service and then accepting the message as processed based on the response from the service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a service expose a WCF endpoint to accept a Command, process it, and return an error/return code which is then delivered in the web service response.

Check out the article [How Do I Expose An NServiceBus Endpoint As A Web/Wcf Service?](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/862411-how-do-i-expose-an-nservicebus-endpoint-as-a-web-wcf-service-) on the NServiceBus support site, but be aware that as of NServiceBus 4.0 (currently in beta) the `Webservice` option the article mentions is being removed, as Microsoft has [officialy declared ASMX web services to be a "legacy technology".](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/)

That aside, a WcfService should work quite well for this scenario.